# How to align items in a table

Tags: tables, align

I am using the following code

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline 
Something & Else \\ \hline 
$(W/L)1$ & $\dfrac{28}{3.6}$ \\ [5ex]
\hline 
\end{tabular}
```

How do I get the second column to be in the center . Now the 2 touches the top of the line. Could someone please help me out?

Comment: Why do you enclose the tabular in a `figure` environment?

Comment: To get some spaces around instead of linebreaks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can insert some space to the top by inserting a rule with no width as a strut or you use the highly recommended `booktabs` package for this.

```
% arara: pdflatex

 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{float}
 \usepackage{mathtools}
 \usepackage{booktabs}

 \begin{document}
\begin{table}[H] % this should be a table, I guess.
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
        \hline 
        Something & Else \\ \hline 
        \rule{0pt}{20pt}$(W/L)1$ & $\dfrac{28}{3.6}$ \\[10pt]
        \hline 
    \end{tabular} 
\end{table}
\begin{table}[H]
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
        \toprule 
        Something & Else \\ \midrule 
        $(W/L)1$ & $\dfrac{28}{3.6}$ \\
        \bottomrule 
    \end{tabular} 
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @GatsbyGreat Glad to hear that. If you want to use my first approach, I strongly recommend to take Mico's version.

Answer (score 3):

You could insert a "top strut" in the numerator of the fraction expression. Since you insert `5ex` of vertical whitespace after the data row, I would suggest you make the "top strut" `5ex` tall.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for "\dfrac" macro
\newcommand\TopStrut{\rule{0pt}{5ex}} % "top" strut

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
  \hline 
  Something & Else \\ \hline 
  $(W/L)1$ & $\dfrac{28\TopStrut}{3.6}$ \\ [5ex]
  \hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Or with help good old ˙mdwtab`:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools} % loads amsmath
\usepackage{mdwtab}

    \begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|Mc|Mc|}
    \hlx{hv}
\text{Something}    &   \text{Else}         \\ 
    \hlx{vhv}
(W/L)1              &   \dfrac{28}{3.6}     \\
    \hlx{vh}
\end{tabular}
    \end{document}
```

which gives:
[image]

Of course, if you wish, you can omit vertical lines.

Comment: How would you handle the OP's use case of `5ex` of extra vertical whitespace *below* the fraction term?

Comment: @mico, I didn't understood, that this is demand. I will check, how to do this in mdwtab. If I recall correctly, you can adjust option `v`,

Comment: @Mico, here is solution: instead of `hlx{vh}` use `hlxv[2][3ex]h` (in the first `[...]` is number of column, to which you like to add extra vertical space and in the second `[...]` is amount of extra vertical space.